# Can I control a Microchip USB3300 Transceiver with a USB 1.1 host controller IP?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

As the title says I want to connect to a USB 3300 transceiver (USB 2.0 revision) using a USB 1.1 host controller IP block.

Is this possible or do I need to conform to the USB 2.0 specification as the IP core I have located so far is the only one located so far the older USB rev. 1.1?

I am not looking for generic host functionality.  From what I understand I only need it to support a single peripheral device (a usb mouse) using OTG (On-The-Go) specification.

I am not concerned about speed but want to make sure this is compatible.

What information can help in determining this?  Any help is appreciated.

Host Core

https://opencores.org/projects/usbhostslave

Answer (score 2):

No, that won't work at all. The IP core you're looking at was designed to operate with a USB 1.1 tranceiver like [the Fairchild USB1T11A](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/fairchild%20semiconductor_usb1t11a-320893.pdf), which is little more than a differential driver/receiver. A USB 2.0 transceiver like [the Microchip USB3300](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00001783C.pdf) is a wholly different device -- it performs high-speed de/serialization and presents an 8-bit parallel interface.

Comment: +1. However, it should be clarified that USB3300 ULPI PHY can serve all USB 2.0 modes, HS, FS, and LS, when its "function control register" is set to proper mode.Obviously, to use the ULPI PHY as USB3300, the core must be designed for the UTMI/ULPI interface.